# Is it possible to run launch GPU process on virtual server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, gpu

I've got Linux server (specs: [vServer CX40](https://www.hetzner.de/it/hosting/produkte_vserver/cx40)) and installed chromium-browser via apt-get and run it via X11 forwarding in Putty on Windows by having Xming server. It works, but it complains about GPU process:

```
Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal:~$ chromium-browser
[20310:20310:0928/235706:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(386)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[20310:20310:0928/235706:ERROR:gl_surface_x11.cc(252)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[20310:20310:0928/235706:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(343)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[20310:20310:0928/235706:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(369)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[20278:20304:0928/235729:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(119)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[20278:20304:0928/235729:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(119)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[20278:20304:0928/235846:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(119)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[20278:20304:0928/235847:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(119)] Failed to launch GPU process.
```

Is it possible to use GPU process on such server? Or it isn't possible, because it's virtualized?

How can I check this?

---

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-22-generic x86_64)

```
Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 IDE [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 USB [Natoma/Triton II] (rev 01)
00:01.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Device 1234:1111 (rev 02)
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio network device
00:04.0 SCSI storage controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio SCSI
00:05.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Red Hat, Inc Virtio memory balloon

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Device 1234:1111 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc Device 1100
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at febd0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Expansion ROM at febc0000 [disabled] [size=64K]
```

Comment: Can you explain why you believe the later errors are **not** a consequence of the first one, *i.e.* your not having a version of GLX  at least 1.3?

Comment: It could be that it's related to missing GLX, possibly. This post suggest to upgrade [Xorg](http://askubuntu.com/a/110356/78223), I'll try that.

Comment: I've still have some issues upgrading GLX, I've posted answer, but it isn't the perfect solution and I think it still needs some work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this message:

> GLX 1.3 or later is required.

the **GLX 1.3 or later** needs to be installed. The version can be checked by:

```
glxinfo | grep version
```

<sup>Install `glxinfo` tool via `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`.</sup>

To check which library needs to be upgraded or installed, run:

```
$ ldd $(which glxinfo) | grep -i glx
        libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fc48a44d000)
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0
libxcb-glx0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0
$ sudo apt-get install libxcb-glx0
```

However if the update is not available, the custom [PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers) needs to be added with newer packages, e.g.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

<sup>This is also suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/110356/78223).</sup>

And try again:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-glx0 libgl1-mesa-glx
```